# How to get reference to new row being added in an Infragistics UltraGrid in VB.net win form

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, infragistics, bindinglist, ultrawingrid

I have a property declared as follows:

```
public property FinalList as new BindingList(of Entity)
```

Entity is a specific entity created via entity framework.  I also have an UltraGrid whose DataSource property that is bound to FinalList.

When the program loads, it adds a bunch of items from an EF DbSet into FinalList based on some rules.  Because the UltraGrid DataSource is bound to FinalList, the grid automatically updates with those initial items.

The UltraGrid is set to allow new rows to be added via the TemplateAddNewRow feature.  And here is where my problem occurs.  Adding the rows to the grid properly adds the same new rows to FinalList...but since FinalList originates from a subset of an EF DbSet, I need to make those new rows also get added to the DbSet so that the changes will be sent to the database when the user saves.

Originally, the Datasource was not databound to a BindingList...it was just set equal to...but the size of lists got to the point where having to re-create the lists when certain things happened was causing the screen to be too slow...So I changed things to data binding.  Anyways, I had a bit of code that used to work pre-binding.

```
Private Sub grid_InitializeTemplateAddRow(sender As Object, e As InitializeTemplateAddRowEventArgs) Handles grid.InitializeTemplateAddRow
    If e.TemplateAddRow.ListObject IsNot Nothing then 
        'do something to add the row to EF DbSet
    End If
End Sub
```

This code worked fine before binding.  Now, ListObject is always nothing...so this doesn't work.  There also is a property

```
e.TemplateAddRow.IsAddNew
```

This is always false as well...so I can't use that either.

I suspect the issue lies in the fact that since everything is bound, UltraGrid can't tell if something is new or not...so I think I need to intercept the row immediately before/after it gets added to FinalList, rather than added to the grid.  According to IntelliSense, FinalList doesn't have any events that I can tie into.  Any thoughts?

Comment: But UltraGrid has BeforeRowInsert and AfterRowInsert events. Can you  get the info from those event and their args? (AfterRowInsert in particular)

Comment: BeforeRowInsert doesn't have a reference to the row being created, so I can't use that.

Comment: AfterRowInsert executes twice, once when initializing the template and once after the row gets moved from the new area to the grid

Comment: So in that case, I end up with an essentially empty row and a good row that would get committed to the database.  I want to avoid having a bunch of rules that determines when rows get committed, because I will be making a ton of changes to these tables and don't want to have to remember to update my rules...